# ADO Not Supporting XML in stored procedure

Tags: c++, xml, sql-server-2005, visual-c++, stored-procedures

When trying to execute store procedure in sql server from c++ i am getting ce = {DB_E_ERRORSINCOMMAND}

c++ code is

```
pCom->Execute(NULL,NULL,adCmdStoredProc);
```

executing from command object..

store procedure look like this

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTicketDetails]
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @inputXml XML;
SET NOCOUNT ON
set @inputXml = '<Record><studentid>143</studentid></Record>';

INSERT INTO dbo.sample (studentid)
    SELECT 
        @inputXml.value( 'studentid[1]', 'int' ) AS studentid        
    FROM @inputXml.nodes('/Record') a(y)
END
```

here inserstion is done with xml, if insertion done without xml working properly. i think it problem with xml or we cant access the xml functionality of sql server from c++?

Comment: please show your ADO code please?

Answer (score 1):

The error is not in ADO it's in to your SQL which is returning a NULL. I suspect  dbo.sample (studentid) doesn't allow nulls.

change the insert statement to:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.sample (studentid)
SELECT  
    @inputXml.value( '(/Record/studentid)[1]', 'int' ) AS studentid
```

or

```
INSERT INTO dbo.sample (studentid)
SELECT  
    @inputXml.value( '(//studentid)[1]', 'int' ) AS studentid         
FROM @inputXml.nodes('/Record') a(y)
```

Comment: problem is this store procedure not working with ado. when i try to execute from sqlserver execution done and inserted properly. when i m executing from my application it throws exception. if i removed xml functionality it working correctly.